# how to skip execution of phpunit data provider method

Tags: phpunit, dataprovider

One of my phpunit tests uses a dataset (that is provided by a dataprovider) that takes quite a long time to generate. When I exclude this test from execution, its dataprovider method is still executed.

How can I skip execution of a dataprovider?

Answer (score 0):

If you're skipping the slow tests from inside the test, using `$this->markTestSkipped()`, you can't prevent the dataProvider to be executed.

This is because PHPUnit must get the data that will be passed to the tests, before executing them.

Possible solutions:

1. Set an environment variable from command-line (`-d key[=value]` option) that will be read both by the dataProvider and the slow test. The dataProvider will return a dummy array and the test will mark itself as skipped.
2. Mark the test as slow using the `@group` annotation and use the `--exclude-group` command line option so the slow group tests won't be executed
3. Refactoring the test so no dataProviders are used, assuming the inconvenience of not having the tests as distinct cases.

Comment: I will try solution 1. Solution 2 doesn't help: when using --exclude-group, the dataprovider will still be executed. 3. I use a dataprovider to have distinct test cases.